# Rails Nested Attributes Not Saving In A One To One Relation (API Only)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For some reason, none of my one-to-one relations are being saved in rails when using the `accepts_nested_attributes_for`

Take example of this, there is a `User` table and a `Profile` table. There's a direct relationship between them and each user is required to have a profile

Therefore on `POST /users/` it's necessary to create the associated profile for the user.

However, for some reason that does not happen and I get a NULL column violation error as all of my nested attributes are being ignored despite being permitted.

My user model is like this:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  authenticates_with_sorcery!

  attr_writer :profile_attributes

  has_many :accounts, foreign_key: 'users_id'
  has_one :profile, foreign_key: 'user_id'
  has_many :authentications, :dependent => :destroy

  ...

  validates :password, password: true, on: :create
  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true, format: { with: URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP } 

  before_create :set_user_type
  before_save :build_profile

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile, reject_if: :all_blank
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :authentications

  ...
end
```

With the profile model like this:

```rb
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: 'user_id', polymorphic: true, optional: true

  attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name

  ...

  validates_date :birthday, before: -> { 16.years.ago }, before_message: 'must be at least 16 years old', allow_nil: true

  validates :profile_image, url: { allow_nil: true, no_local: true }
  validates :first_name, presence: true
  validates :last_name, presence: true
  validates :gender, enum: genders

  ...
end
```

And the UsersController (create method)

```rb
 def create
    user = User.create user_params

    raise RBError::ValidationError.new(user.errors) unless user.save
    respond user.as_json, :created
  end

private
  def user_params
    params.require(:data)
      .permit(:email, :password, :phone_number, {
        profile_attributes: [
          :first_name, :last_name, :gender, :dob, :profile_image
        ]
      })
  end
```

The JSON request is like so:

```
{
    "data": {
        "email": [omitted],
        "password": [omitted],
        "profile_attributes": {
            "first_name": "John",
            "last_name": "Doe"
        }
    }
}
```

With this response error

```
 "#<ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation: PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column \"first_name\" violates not-null constraint\nDETAIL:  Failing row contains (23, 31, null, null, null, null, 2019-08-10 11:49:40.021683, 2019-08-10 11:49:40.021683, null, null).\n: INSERT INTO \"profiles\" (\"user_id\", \"created_at\", \"updated_at\") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING \"id\">",
```

So as you can see ALL of the attributes sent in the request are being completely ignored. I have no idea why and it's been driving my crazy. I can't seem to find anything remotely similar to the issue I'm having.

All of the parameters are being permitted too and the validations on the profile model work as expected.

```
 Parameters: {"data"=>{"email"=>"sample@fgmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "profile_attributes"=>{"first_name"=>"John", "last_name"=>"Doe"}}, "user"=>{}}
<ActionController::Parameters {"email"=>"sample@fgmail.com", "password"=>[OMITTED], "profile_attributes"=><ActionController::Parameters {"first_name"=>"John", "last_name"=>"Doe"} permitted: true>} permitted: true>
```

Comment: You have `before_save :build_profile`, what does the `build_profile` method do? Also why do you define `attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name` on your `Profile` model? `first_name` and `last_name` should be defined by ActiveRecord, maybe you have overridden accessors for first and last name and that is the reason why it doesn't work. And same thing maybe happened with `attr_writer :profile_attributes` on the `User` model, it should be also defined directly by ActiveRecord.

Comment: Honestly I don't know why the accessors and writers are there, I added it there in hope of making it work since it still didnt work without it. (Yes, i'm a bit new to rails) The build_profile is defined by the ActiveRecord for all relations, like you canm call build_* and it's supposed to (or to my knowledge) build/create the relation with the associated attributes

Comment: Ok, try to delete lines `attr_writer :profile_attributes`, `before_save :build_profile` in `User` and `attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name` in `Profile` from your code. You should not need them, all of these things should be served via ActiveRecord. And then try whether it works, maybe it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use `attr_writer` or `attr_accessor` in Rails models*.

```
attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name
```

Will overwrite the setters that ActiveRecord has already created by reading the database schema. These setters don't just set the instance variable, they also trigger the "dirty tracking" that keeps track of changes to the model that should be saved to the database.

Your validations will still pass since @first_name and @last_name are not nil but when you call `@user.save`  `ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Dirty#changes_to_save` will have nil values for :first_name and :last_name.

`attr_writer :profile_attributes` is actually worse. You're taking [the setter that ActiveRecord::NestedAttributes declares](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b9ca94caea2ca6a6cc09abaffaad67b447134079/activerecord/lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb#L407) which is a fancier metaprogramming version of:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def profile_attributes=(hash)
    self.build_profile(hash)
  end
end
```

and replacing it with this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def profile_attributes=(value)
    @profile_attributes = value
  end
end
```

Which basically does nothing at all.

Another problem is `before_save :build_profile` which will call `#build_profile` with nil. Which will actually overwrite whatever attributes you have previously passed. If you need to "seed" the association for the form inputs to appear do it in the controller:

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  @user.build_profile
end
```

Comment: * Well, almost never. But at least never use it for table backed attributes, associations or anything which should be done with the attributes API.

Comment: Thanks for that. What eventually worked for me was something like this 
   `user = User.new(user_params)
    user.build_profile user_params[:profile_attributes]`